# Removing the duplicate values in QCombo Box

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-2

In my plugin, there is a combo box which lists city names for a particular state. FOr example, if i chose a particular state and city will be some 20 names in the dropdown. But the first name alone appearing in the dropdown is repeated thrice. Other names are once in the dropdown.
The fuction which i wrote for listing the city names in combo box is shown below.

```
 def findTheCityNames(self):
    layers = self.iface.mapCanvas().layers()
    for layer in layers:
        if layer.type() == QgsMapLayer.VectorLayer:
            layers = self.iface.activeLayer()
            if layer > 0:
                self.dlg.Citycombo.clear()
                ct = self.dlg.Statecombo.currentText()
                st = "name_1='"+ct+"'"
                exp = QgsExpression(st)
                fidAndVal = {}
                #QMessageBox.information(self.iface.mainWindow(), "info", st)
                layer = self.iface.activeLayer()
                iterFeat = layer.getFeatures()
                for f in iterFeat:
                    val = exp.evaluate(f)
                    if bool(val):
                        attrs = f.attributes()
                        idx = layer.fieldNameIndex('name')
                        cityName = f.attributes()[idx]
                        fidInt = f.id()
                        fidAndVal[fidInt] = cityName
                        for x in fidAndVal.keys():
                            self.dlg.Citycombo.addItem(fidAndVal[x])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily. First, store the city names in a 'list' and then use a 'set' to remove the duplicates.

```
def findTheCityNames(self):
cities = []
layers = self.iface.mapCanvas().layers()
for layer in layers:
    if layer.type() == QgsMapLayer.VectorLayer:
        layers = self.iface.activeLayer()
        if layer > 0:
            self.dlg.Citycombo.clear()
            ct = self.dlg.Statecombo.currentText()
            st = "name_1='"+ct+"'"
            exp = QgsExpression(st)
            fidAndVal = {}
            #QMessageBox.information(self.iface.mainWindow(), "info", st)
            layer = self.iface.activeLayer()
            iterFeat = layer.getFeatures()
            for f in iterFeat:
                val = exp.evaluate(f)
                if bool(val):
                    attrs = f.attributes()
                    idx = layer.fieldNameIndex('name')
                    cityName = f.attributes()[idx]
                    fidInt = f.id()
                    fidAndVal[fidInt] = cityName
                    for x in fidAndVal.keys():
                        cities.append(fidAndVal[x])

for city in set(cities):
    self.dlg.Citycombo.addItem(city)
```